# converting looped mysql query into a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL query

```
$var = 123;
$sql="SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM `table1`  WHERE `COL1`='$var'";
```

The results from this query (looped) are used to get the count for each row from another table.

```
$value = $row['COL2'];
$var2= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT MY_COL FROM `table2` WHERE `column1` ='".$var1."' AND column2 = $value"));
```

I tried this to combine the two

```
$sql = "SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, COUNT(B.MY_COL) FROM `table1` A LEFT JOIN `table2` B ON A.COL2 = B.column2 WHERE A.COL1=$var"
```

but the results are wrong. Is using ON **A.COL2 = B.column2** correct? 
How can I combine these two queries into one to decrease calls to mysql?

Table1 has records which may not be in Table2.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
$sql = "SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, COUNT(B.MY_COL) FROM `table1` A LEFT JOIN `table2` B ON A.COL2 = B.column2 AND A.COL1=$var"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var2= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT MY_COL FROM `table2` WHERE `column1` ='".$var1."' AND column2 
  IN (
    SELECT COL2 FROM `table1`  WHERE `COL1`='$var'
  )
));
```

Use MySQL WHERE IN

**Note:** Don't use mysql_ functions, they are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP versions.

Comment: I need all the rows from table1 and their subsequent count from table2 only when column2.table2 = COL2.table1

Comment: You need to use different queries for each column as subquery should return only one column.